# How to attach .d.ts to draft?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

To attach declarations (.d.ts) using `typings`. But in cases with `rx.js` (4.1) `typings` in repository older version (2.5). But when you install `rx.js` using `npm` is a [folder with the current declarations](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/tree/master/ts) (.d.ts). 
How to add a link to this folder in your `typings`? I use WebStorm and it is very difficult linter.

***UPD: 0.0.1***

Here is how I have written in `typings/main.d.ts`

```
/// <reference path="main/ambient/react/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="main/ambient/react-dom/index.d.ts" />
```

then import

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

With rx you get such a scheme

```
/// <reference path="main/ambient/react/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="main/ambient/react-dom/index.d.ts" />

/// <reference path="../node_modules/rx/ts/rx.d.ts" />
```

But when import

```
import * as Rx from 'rx';
```

rx is highlighted in red as an error.

Comment: Are you using `typings` or `tsd` ?!

Comment: @onreachable, ```typings```

Comment: You don't need to add it. If a project comes with it's own definitions, those definitions will automatically be used with `import * as Rx from "rx";`

Comment: You don't need the reference path at all.